# Host Website using IIS 7.5 ,Windows server 2008 R2 and .net framework 4.5

Tags: .net, iis

I have a windows server 2008 R2 SP1 and iis 7.5 Machine.we are developed .net framework 4.5 using web application.

Now i faced one issue ,first i will open iis 7.5 and create one website then set physical path and available port.then click application pool config select .net framework 4.0 .after then enable the directory browsing also.**finally to browsing the site not work.it is not show any error always still loading site in Browser.**

**But i will tried iis 7.5 but windows 7 OS in this same setting configuration site working fine.**

so this is the problem i want host iis 7.5 and windows server 2008 r2,why does not support i don't know please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your fire wall first. Is port 80 opened ?

Secondly, you should browse your website using localhost on your server (remember to add binding localhost for testing purpose), browsing on server will give you detail error than test browsing on client machine

Comment: We have already tried this step but local host page loading.it does'nt show any error.

Comment: Can you check for more details, first try browse an image, js or css file on your server. If it is ok, there may be no problem with IIS and you should check your code.  Normally, If website keep loading, I think problem is fire wall, you should telnet to check it. You can check window event log for IIS Exception causes by your code

Comment: Yes  we have already checked one simple .aspx page host in iis .it is work fine.but code having any issue mean's my assumption is iis 7.5 and os windows 7 that time this code is work fine.

Comment: we have one doubt anything Add Role related issue is there.

Comment: we will try to check telnet and window event log after send comment to you thanks Khanh